# List processing, convert list to apostrophe and comma separated records, surrounded by brackets

Tags: bash, awk

I have a list in a file named Target_id_convert.txt

```
70S ribosome
ALK tyrosine kinase receptor
ATP
ATP synthase
```

Desired output

```
('70S ribosome','ALK tyrosine kinase receptor','ATP','ATP synthase')
```

I have written this code

```
sed -e "s/'/'\\\\''/g;s/\(.*\)/'\1'/" Target_id_convert.txt  > Target_id_convert1.txt
tr '\n' ',' < Target_id_convert1.txt > Target_id_convert_output.txt
```

I then have to manually edit the file and add () in the Target_id_convert_output.txt file, Kindly let me know how to do it efficiently and all in one go, as It is all supposed to be automated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your records are double new-line separated, I would go with a `sed`/`awk` combo:

```
<file sed "/[^[:blank:]]/ s/.*/'&'/g" |
awk '{ $1=$1; print "(" $0 ")" }' RS= FS='\n' OFS=,
```

If the input is:

```
70S ribosome
ALK tyrosine kinase receptor
ATP
ATP synthase

70S ribosome
ALK tyrosine kinase receptor
ATP
ATP synthase
```

Output is:

```
('70S ribosome','ALK tyrosine kinase receptor','ATP','ATP synthase')
('70S ribosome','ALK tyrosine kinase receptor','ATP','ATP synthase')
```

Comment: ++ For the multilist input.

Answer (score 5):

This awk one-liner should do what you want:

```
awk -v q="'" '{$0=q $0 q;printf "%s%s", (NR==1?"(":","),$0}END{print ")"}' file
```

I declared a var `q` to have single quote (`'`), to avoid many escaping.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat f.awk
BEGIN {
    sep = ""
    b = "'"
}

{
    ans = ans sep b $0 b
    sep = ","
}

END { print "(" ans ")" }
```

Usage:

```
awk -f f.awk file
```

Answer (score 2):

To offer an *alternative* that uses **[`trl`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/trl)**, a utility of mine for *tr*ansforming text between single- and multi-*l*ine forms:

```
$ trl -S, -D\' -W'()'  <<<$'70S ribosome\nALK tyrosine kinase receptor\nATP\nATP synthase'
('70S ribosome','ALK tyrosine kinase receptor','ATP','ATP synthase')
```

- Since the input is multi-line, the default output format is single-line.
- `-S,` sets the output *s*eparator to `,` (what to place between items)
- `-D\'` sets the output item *d*elimiter to `'` (what to enclose each item in)
- `-W'()'` *w*raps (encloses) the resulting output line in `(` and `)`.

---

#### Installation of `trl` from the [npm registry](https://www.npmjs.com/package/trl) (Linux and macOS)

<sup>Note: Even if you don't use Node.js, its package manager, `npm`, works across platforms and is easy to install; try

[`curl -L https://git.io/n-install | bash`](https://github.com/mklement0/n-install)</sup>

With [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) installed, install as follows:

```
[sudo] npm install trl -g
```

**Note**:

- Whether you need `sudo` depends on how you installed Node.js and whether you've [changed permissions later](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions); if you get an `EACCES` error, try again with `sudo`.
- The `-g` ensures [*global* installation](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-npm-packages-globally) and is needed to put `trl` in your system's `$PATH`.

#### Manual installation (any Unix platform with `bash`)

- Download [this `bash` script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mklement0/trl/stable/bin/trl) as `trl`.
- Make it executable with `chmod +x trl`.
- Move it or symlink it to a folder in your `$PATH`, such as `/usr/local/bin` (OSX) or `/usr/bin` (Linux).

Comment: Great Stuff! `++`, first time seeing an answer from a person who has written the tool himself. This should be packaged as part of distro! so naive!

Comment: I appreciate the nice feedback, @Inian.
It's always a little tricky to promote one's own stuff, but this was a perfect fit.
Yes, it's a utility I too wish came with every distro, along with [a few others](https://www.npmjs.com/~mklement0).

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
awk -v s1="'" -v s2="'," -v s3="(" -v s4=")" 'NR==1{printf("%s",s3)} last{printf("%s",s1 last s2)} {last=$0} END{printf("%s\n",last s1 s4)}'   Input_file
```

I am defining the variables like s1, s2,s3 and s4 with their values. Then I am printing ( on very first line and then taking line's values into variable named last and printing the lines values with value', in END section of code printing the line's value with ') too. I am considering your Input_file is having same values as shown sample Input_file.

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
$ cat f
70S ribosome
ALK tyrosine kinase receptor
ATP
ATP synthase
$ awk -v line=$(wc -l < f) -v ORS="" 'BEGIN{printf "("} {if(NR < line) {print a$0b}} END {print a$0a")\n"}' b="'," a="'" f
('70S ribosome','ALK tyrosine kinase receptor','ATP','ATP synthase')
```

Comment: I suggest not reading the input file _twice_ (once just to count the number of lines).

Comment: @mklement0 - Thanks for your suggestion, I am working on performance improvement of this solution.

Answer (score 1):

In awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{q="\047";RS="";FS="\n";OFS=q","q}{$0="("q $0 "\)"q;$1=$1}1' file
```

Output for single list file:

```
('70S ribosome','ALK tyrosine kinase receptor','ATP','ATP synthase')
```

Explained:

```
awk '
BEGIN {
    q="\047"             # define q to - well, \047
    RS=""                # see below (*
    FS="\n"              # newline is input field separator 
    OFS=q","q            # output field separator to ,
}
{
    $0="(" q $0 "\)" q   # surround record with single quotes
    $1=$1                # rebuild the record
} 1' file                # print
```

*) From the GNU awk documentation: *By a special dispensation, an empty string as the value of RS indicates that records are separated by one or more blank lines. When RS is set to the empty string, each record always ends at the first blank line encountered. The next record doesn’t start until the first nonblank line that follows.* This allow empty-line separated lists to be processed. For example, using @Thor's sample data, output would be:

```
('70S ribosome','ALK tyrosine kinase receptor','ATP','ATP synthase)'
('70S ribosome','ALK tyrosine kinase receptor','ATP','ATP synthase)'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set your field and record separators, recompile the record and print:

```
$ awk -v RS= -v s="('" -v ORS="')\n" -F'\n' -v OFS="','" '{$1=s$1}1' file
('70S ribosome','ALK tyrosine kinase receptor','ATP','ATP synthase')
```